# Problem whille adding project into the websephere 6.1

Tags: java, webserver, websphere

I am using IBM web-sphere 6.1 as a application server and eclipse as IDE. so i have one project name as MobileBank.ear which contain deployment descriptor file which has one module name as amsejb.jar which is ejb project and some jar files. so while adding MobileBank.ear into the server i am getting the following error " **Web-Sphere v6.0 only supports J2EE 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4 Enterprise applications.**" due to this error i am not able to deploy my ear can anyone guide me please... also MobileBank.ear contains web project though i am not able to add the ear.  Kindly Guide me...

Thanks in advance...
Vinod

Comment: Also if anyone know the web-sphere application server 6.0 installation directory path???

Answer (score 0):

I am using IBM web-sphere 6.1 ... Web-Sphere v6.0 only supports ... Are you sure you are using WAS 6.1 ?? May be this is what causing the problem

Comment: @Vinod ... I read some where that there is no supported adapter to use WAS 6.1 with eclipse. You have to use IBM RAD to connect to WAS 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 6.1 really doesn't support more than 1.4 and you're attempting to use newer versions.. You should

- Edit the project facets in the project properties to utilize older versions
- Not select 6.0 when generating the project as the target. That is used for the remote deployment etc. Eclipse does not really support 6.1/7.x deployment so please generate the generic projects instead.

Answer (score 0):

i deleted the EAR folder ,created new Enterprise Application Project and added all project in that . error got resolved .

Answer (score 0):

I am using WAS 7.0

U need to change the WebSphere Application Server version under Coniguration section while creating a project in Eclipse/RAD.

Then Dynamic Web module version will get changed from 3.0 to 2.5

Answer (score 0):

While creating a dynamic web project, 
-- On entering the "project name"
     -- we have an option to check "Add project to EAR"
             -- Enter the EAR name 
             -- choose the EAR version on of these - 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 and 5.0

On doing this, we would be able to add the EAR to WAS (I have been using v7)